# htaccess redirection for joomla page

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

How to do an htaccess redirection for the following

```
http://goozga.com/demo/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=70
```

needs to rewrite the above URL to

```
http://goozga.com/demo/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=73
```

please help me?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why would you want to redirect 1 article to another?

Comment: one page contains more than one atricles, so if any of the artilce seperatly comes by search engine we need to redirect to correct page where it is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content&view=article&id=70$
RewriteRule .* index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=73 [L]
```

Note that your question has nothing to do with Joomla but depends on Apache's `mod_rewrite` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Within Joomla, you can also use the Redirect component. You would just have to add a new redirect rule with the first URL as the source and the second as the destination URL.